# Why is the static part of a jsp streamed AFTER the java part?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

I worte the follwing jsp sample page using Google App Engine in Eclipse Indigo:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>    
<% response.getWriter().println("<h1><a href=\"VotingMainPage.jsp\">  Hello World <br></a></h1>"); %>
</body>
</html>
```

To my confusion the output to the local browser is:

```
<h1><a href="VotingMainPage.jsp">  Hello World <br></a></h1>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>          
</body>
</html>
```

The text generated by the java code comes before the static html, although intthe page it is inside the static code.

What do i have to do, to get things printed to the response in the order i have them in my code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using scriptlets, then this will do the job.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>    
<%= "<h1><a href=\"VotingMainPage.jsp\">  Hello World <br></a></h1>" %>
</body>
</html>
```

But you are better off using JSTL.

---

The reason that your code doesn't work is that GAE's JSP compiler is apparently wrapping the JSPWriter in a buffered writer of some kind.  When you use the writer directly, your output is effectively "overtaking" the stuff that the JSP has written to the buffered writer.

Comment: My code is only a reduced sample of a larger function that generates text at runtime. I can not use static content here.

Comment: @REDSOFTADAIR - the stuff inside the `<%= ... %>` can be any Java expression.

Answer (score 1):

Use `out` rather than `response.getWriter()` to use the same writer the JSP page is using.